# JavaScript shortcut to create elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I've created a personal API for creating elements for an HTML page. I would like feedback on efficiency, particularly in creating buttons and labels. Any and all feedback is appreciated and considered

**tag.js**

```
/*
* Shortcuts for creatings different tags
*/
function createLabel(text) {
    let label_tag = document.createElement('label');
    let label_tag_text = document.createTextNode(text);
    tabel_tag.appendChild(label_tag_text);
    return label_tag;
}

function createButton(type) {
    /* need to manually add .onclick when creating button */
    let button_tag = document.createElement('button');
    button_tag.type = type;
    return button_tag;
}

function createInput(type, id) {
    let input_tag = document.createElement('input');
    input_tag.type = type;
    input_tag.id = id;
    return input_tag;
}

function createDiv(id) {
    let div_tag = document.createElement('div');
    div_tag.id = id;
    return div_tag;
}

function createTag(tag) {
    /*
    * Used for creating basic tags (<p>, <br>, <hr>, etc)
    * Any tag that doesn't often use an ID, TYPE, NAME, CLASS, etc
    */
    return document.createElement(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of repeated code. If you follow the same design you will end up with a huge list of `create???()` functions

You could simplify to a single function, and pass tag name and an optional properties containing element and style properties.

```
const createTag = (tag, props = {}) => {
    const style = props.style;
    if (style) { delete props.style }
    const el = Object.assign(document.createElement,props);
    if (style) { Object.assign(el.style, style) }
    return el;
}
```

Thus you can create tags

```
createTag("input", {type : "button", id : "buttonId"});
createTag("button", {value : "Click me"});
createTag("div", {textContent: "abc", id: "abcId", className: "abcDiv", style: {width: "10px"}});
```

If you did want to have a function to create each type then it would pay to put them together.

```
const createDOM = {
    label(...
    button(...
    input(...
    div(...
    // and so on
}
```